# What's the difference between "comply" and "conform"?

Tags: meaning, difference, verbs

I was wondering what is the difference between "comply" and "conform". Meaning of those two verbs seem quite similar. Could you help me?

And is it okay to say "comply to someone" or "conform to someone" like "submit to someone" or "follow to someone"?

Comment: When you say "seem similar",  what definitions are you using.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/comply  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conform

Comment: You comply _with_ a request or rule when you do as you were asked - or you conform _to_ it. You don't comply to a person.

Answer (score 3):

They are rather different in meaning.

"Comply" means "follow an order".  You don't don't comply to a person, you comply *with an order".

> He complied with my instruction to wear a mask.

"Conform", on the other hand, means being the same as other people (or another person) There might be no "rule".

> He conformed with the rest of the class and wore his mask.

If there is a rule that applies to everyone, you can conform to that rule

> He conformed to the mask rule.

So the main meanings are different.  They can both mean "obey", but "conform" means "obey a rule that everyone has to obey", but "comply" means "obey a particular command

Comment: "Conform" does not necessarily apply to "with a rule", but merely just with the prevailing social custom. "In his new neighborhood, Fred observed that everybody wore a red hat on Mondays. Wishing to conform, he went out and bought one."

Comment: Yes, "Conform" means being the same as other people (or another person)