# Conform with or conform to

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

Is there any difference in meaning of **conform *with*** and **conform *to***?

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conform-to-with-sth) does not seem to make any difference and gives both prepositions with "conform"

> Before buying the baby's car seat , make sure that it **conforms to** the official safety standards.

I found a discussion on [this site](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/conform-to-or-conform-with.1772965/#:%7E:text=%22Conform%20to%22%20suggests%20%22obey,with%22%20suggests%20%22fit%22.) where native speakers say that there is a difference. One of the members says:

> I feel a difference. "Conform to" suggests "obey", while "conform with" suggests "fit"

So if I use "conform **with**" in the sentence above, will it change the meaning?

In general, is there a difference in both prepositions or we can use them interchangeably?

Comment: ***Conform to*** is more common, but [both prepositions occur.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conforms+to+the+standard%2Cconforms+with+the+standard&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconforms%20to%20the%20standard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconforms%20with%20the%20standard%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cconforms%20to%20the%20standard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconforms%20with%20the%20standard%3B%2Cc0) Ignore anyone who suggests there might be some ***semantic*** distinction. They might believe what they say, but if no-one else knows it, that's a meaningless position.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between “comply” and “conform”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/271227/whats-the-difference-between-comply-and-conform)

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers. The recent tendency to say "I'd like to speak **with** you" rather than the traditional "I'd like to speak **to** you" shows people are shying away from some imagined aggression in the former! "Talk with" and the even more confusing "meet with" (which once actually **meant** something) are cowardly. Despite my best efforts, the expression "to beat with one's wife" has never caught on.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: I'd have thought there's more "aggression" in ***talking to*** than ***with***. Thus *My teenage son is acting up again. Can you **talk to** him?* implies *...give him **a good talking-to**!*, which is inherently negative / aggressive (kinda the opposite of ***sweet-talking***).

Comment: But we never said "Can you talk with him" until recently. The formula didn't exist. I think it was an imagined aggression in "to" that gave birth to it. It's snowflaky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use "conform *to*" = when referring to acting in accordance with a documented set of **rules or standards**, eg "*this product conforms to health and safety standards*".

We use "conform *with*" when referring to a **person or body** that places requirements upon us, eg "*this product conforms with Government guidelines*".